# Return current local datetime in XSL feed from RSS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, xslt, rss

I am currently using xsl to feed weather from rss.weather.com.au. Everything working fine but as soon as i add reference exslt it will not work and show error "**Failed to apply XSLT to the content**". I am using exslt to display the current local time and date

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                extension-element-prefixes="date msxsl"
                xmlns:w="http://rss.weather.com.au/w.dtd">

<xsl:import href="date.xsl" />

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">

<div id="top" >


        <div class="weather rendered">

            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">OpenPopUpPage('<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/link"/>')</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="title">Current temperature: <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:current/@temperature"/>° &#xD;forecast for <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@day"/>:&#xD;<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@min"/>&#176;-<xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@max"/>&#176;, <xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/item/w:forecast[1]/@description"/></xsl:attribute>

            <div class="max"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(/rss/channel/item/w:current/@temperature, '0')"/><span class="deg">&#176;</span></div>


            <div class="date"><xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()" />"</div>


        </div>



</div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


>
```

I have already look this example below but it still not resolve my issue
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950776.aspx

Comment: I think this post might be helpful
[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892344/convert-a-string-to-date-format-in-xslt)